# How to select aggregate of multiple columns (no group by)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Say I have a summary table like this:

```
AcitivityCache
(
   pkId (bigint, PK),
   Date (DateTime),
   OfficeId (int, FK)
   TransactionCount (int),
   RejectCount (int),
   InvitationCount (int),
   RequestCount (int)
   ...
   --more counts here--
   ...
)
```

Now I need to fetch the total of the counts over a time period (no grouping by office, just sums) which I can do with SQL like this:

```
 SELECT SUM(TransactionCount) as TotalTxCount, SUM(RejectCount) as TotalRejectCount, ...
 FROM ActivityCache 
 WHERE [Date] between '2011-02-01' and '2012-02-01'
```

How can I achieve that with linq? 
Most solutions I have seen so far have some grouping. But for this case, I need no grouping, just the totals. I can do like this:

```
DateTime dateFrom, toDate; // initialized later
...
var q = dbContext.ActivityCaches
                 .Where(a=> a.Date > fromDate && a.Date <= toDate)
                 .GroupBy(a=> 1)
                 .Select(g=> new 
                             {
                                TotalTransactionCount = g.Sum(a => a.TransactionCount),
                                TotalRejectCount = g.Sum(a => a.RejectCount),
                                ...
                                ...
                             });
```

Or, I can fetch the columns first, then take sum programmatically.
Or, I can use an SP (dont like in this case).
Any better ideas (without group by)?

P.S: I wont be able to change the db schema

Comment: Well, the T-SQL is *implicitly* doing a grouping operation, it's just that all records are in the same group, which is the same as what you do with your `GroupBy(a => 1)`. Is there any particular reason you don't like that?

Comment: no reason to dislike :). I was just wondering if there are more ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think LINQ to Entities has some nice query for this situation.

Another solution is using using [Entity SQL (ESQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx)

```
var fromDate = new DateTime(2011, 02, 01);
var toDate = new DateTime(2012, 02, 01);
var esql = @"select 
          sum(it.TransactionCount) as SumOfTransactionCount,
          sum(it.RejectCount) as SumOfRejectCount
               from ActivityCaches as it
               where it.Date > @fromDate and it.Date <= @toDate";
var query = CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(esql,
        new ObjectParameter("fromDate", fromDate) ,
        new ObjectParameter("toDate", toDate));
```

Comment: I dont like queries in string though. But, seems you are right on saying "I don't think LINQ to Entities has some nice query for this situation". I will stick to '.GroupBy(g=>1)'

Answer (score 1):

Another ways:

1. Use Entity SQL
2. Apply 3 separate `SUM`s

Answer (score 0):

The Linq **Aggregate()** method allows summing without grouping as below.  I'm afraid that I haven't set it up against a DB so I won't guarantee that that Linq to Sql error won't pop-up.  If that happens you might try an explict ToList() on the ActivityCaches() before doing the Aggregate() but after the where().

**Update**

I updated the code to work with and EF model.
Created a small EF model to replace SomeEntry and updated the data to ensure that I was reading from the DB.

[image: EF Model for ActivityLog]

```
private static ActivityLog Aggregate(ActivityLog agg, ActivityLog entry) {
    agg.TranCount += entry.TranCount;
    agg.ReqCount += entry.ReqCount;
    return agg;
}

[TestMethod]
public void AggregateFirstThree() {

    var context = new TestDBEntities();

    var startDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
    var endDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 3);

    var aggregate = new ActivityLog();

    context.ActivityLogs.Where(entry => entry.Timestamp >= startDate && entry.Timestamp <= endDate).Aggregate(aggregate, Aggregate);

    Assert.AreEqual(66, aggregate.TranCount);
    Assert.AreEqual(36, aggregate.ReqCount);

}

[TestMethod]
public void AggregateLastThree() {

    var context = new TestDBEntities();

    var startDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 4);
    var endDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 6);

    var aggregate = new ActivityLog();

    context.ActivityLogs.Where(entry => entry.Timestamp >= startDate && entry.Timestamp <= endDate).Aggregate(aggregate, Aggregate);

    Assert.AreEqual(75, aggregate.TranCount);
    Assert.AreEqual(45, aggregate.ReqCount);

}
```

hth, 
Alan.

Comment: @Adrian Iftode Just tried it and EF model, worked fine.  Didn't even need to add the ToList(). Will update the code to reflect changes.

Comment: ok, I checked this me too. Unfortunately it doesn't translate this to expected SQL statements. It pulls all the rows then does the aggregate in memory ( as List would be called)

Comment: @Adrian Iftode OK.  Does this mean that it doesn't work, or that it doesn't run the aggregate as SQL on the server.  From the OP I didn't see that as a requirement.

Comment: It means it doesn't run the aggregate on SQL. OP wants select sum(), count(), .. from table, so to run the aggregate on server, not by .Net

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Aggregate". But I don't want to call ToList(); agree with Adrian... Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question where you want to store the result. If you plan to store it in two variables then you could get the data, use .Where() extension method to filter by date range, and then use .Sum() extension method to calculate the sum value. Something along these lines:

```
var result = your_query.Where(m => m.Date >= startingDate && m.Date <= endingDate);
var totalTxCount = result.Sum(m => m.TransactionCount);
var totalRejectCount = result.Sum(m => m.RejectCount);
```